# Close Slide Out Menu when option is selected

Tags: html, css

I found this great slide out menu for a site I'm building.

http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css-off-screen-navigation-menu/

I was wondering if anyone knows how I could go about making the menu close when I select one of the list-items.

The page I'm building is a one page design and I wanted the menu to close for the user when its scrolling to the section they have selected.

Thanks!

Comment: You should read the comments to the article you posted, which do answer your question. Explicitly the answer by "Sylvain Primeau  Ian Baker • 17 days ago".

Comment: I saw that answer and though it worked, it worked with a method that was clunky and I did not like the result.

Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some JavaScript/JQuery to unchecked the checkbox that triggers the menu. I don't think this can be simply done in css/html:

### Event Listener Method

This code listens out for a click on one of the menu items and then removes the checked attribute from the check-box controlling the menu slide out.

**JavaScript:**

```
function addEventListenerList(list, event, fn) {
    for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
        list[i].addEventListener(event, fn, false);
    }
}

var navitems = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item');
addEventListenerList(navitems, 'click', hidemenu); 

function hidemenu() {
    document.getElementById("nav-trigger").checked = false; 
}
```

source: [addEventListener on NodeList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362256/addeventlistener-on-nodelist)

**OR jQuery:** (if you are alreayd using jQuery in your site)

```
$( ".nav-item" ).click(function() {
   $( "#nav-trigger" ).attr('checked', false);
});
```

---

### On Click call Function method

**Or** another method would be to attach the function directly to the menu items on click. You can do this with the following code:

HTML

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" onclick="hidemenu()">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" onclick="hidemenu()>Portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" onclick="hidemenu()>About</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" onclick="hidemenu()>Blog</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" onclick="hidemenu()>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
function hidemenu() {
    document.getElementById("nav-trigger").checked = false; 
}
```

Comment: I'm kind of new to all of this and I saw that. But I didn't quite understand.

Just to be clear, I would add that to the bottom of the page in a <script></script> tag?

Comment: @JasonHess I have added jQuery OR JavaScript code for you to choose. Simply copy the code as shown for the Javascript and add it into <script></script> tags at the bottom of your body and it should work. So it should be: <script language="javascript">document.getElementByClassName(".nav-item").addEventListener("click", hidemenu);

function hidemenu(){
    document.getElementById("nav-trigger").checked = false;
}</script>

Comment: Hey man, thanks but still not working. Here's my code from the script to the bottom.

...
    
    <script language="javascript">
        document.getElementByClassName(".nav-item").addEventListener("click", hidemenu);
        
        function hidemenu(){ 
            document.getElementById("nav-trigger").checked = false; 
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>

Comment: Are you able to include the page/fragment you're working inside a code sample viewer such as jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/ Hard to tell whats' not working from here

Comment: also, the .menubar option is display: none; on some of the breaks. So ignore that.

Comment: @JasonHess Try the JavaScript code in my answer, I have updated the code further. Make sure the menu items you want to trigger it have the class="nav-item" on the <li> tag

Comment: @JasonHess no worries! Glad I can help. Remember to mark the answer that helped you fixed it, helps me and also lets other know what the correct answer was :)