# onmouseover function didn't work

Tags: javascript

All the examples i found online didn't work for me.
All i want is to change color on text when mouse is on it. And when move mouse to get old color (and maybe to change size, but if that is too complicated not yet) I know how to do that in CSS but i am learning JS and thats the way i would like it. 
It is only one word in text so it is Class and not ID.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("akcija").addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
document.getElementsByClassName("akcija").addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);
function mouseOver() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('akcija').style.color = "black";    
}
function mouseOut() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('akcija').style.color = "Blue";    
}
```

```html
<div class="akcija" style="width:200px; height:200px"></div>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [addEventListener on NodeList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362256/addeventlistener-on-nodelist)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript click event listener on class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655189/javascript-click-event-listener-on-class)

Comment: Thank you. I was searching with "onmouseover" and didn't found solution. I didn't know that getElementByClassName is a problem and that i should search for it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` method returns a `nodeList`, so, you can access a `DOM` element using its **index** (zero-based).

Try this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('akcija')[0].style.color = "black";
```

If you are using `ES6` you could do this using `Array.from` method.

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('akcija')).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct code implement IMHO

```js
var akcjijas = document.getElementsByClassName("akcija");

for (var i in akcjijas) {
    if (akcjijas.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        akcjijas[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
        akcjijas[i].addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut); 
    }
}
   
function mouseOver() {
    this.style.color = "black";    
}
function mouseOut() {
    this.style.color = "Blue";    
}
```

```html
<div class="akcija" style="width:200px; height:100px;background-color: yellow">Akcija</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is great. I tried a lot of stuff myself but they never worked. Now it is much clearer for me how to set something up.