# addEventListener on a querySelectorAll() with classList

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to add an event listener but no result came. I know JavaScript has a hoisting feature but I believe I tried all except the correct solution.

```
const cbox = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
function doit() {
  for (let i = 0; i < cbox.length; i++){
    cbox[i].classList.add("red");
  }
}
cbox.addEventListener("click", doit, false);
```

Can somebody spot the mistake I make?

Comment: Why you're using a loop in `doit()` to add the `red` class?

Comment: Because querySelectorAll returns an object soi have to iterate right?

Comment: Yes, it returns an array-like object. Next question would be: why you're not using a loop for assigning the event handler? ;)

Comment: You mean run the for loop inside the handler or vice versa? I tried them both.

Comment: `.querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList` which has no `.addEventListener()` method. You have to add the event on every single item in the list, the same way as you're doing it with the class.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

There are some dissimilarities between the code and the link you have provided. There is no function `doit()` in there.

You have attached `addEvenListener` to the `NodeList` in `cbox.addEventListener("click",.....`, you have to loop through the list and attach the event to the current element:

Try the following:

```js
const cbox = document.querySelectorAll(".box");

 for (let i = 0; i < cbox.length; i++) {
     cbox[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
       cbox[i].classList.toggle("red");
     });
 }
```

```css
*,
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.box {
    width: 10rem;
    height: 10rem;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    transition: .5s all;
}

h3 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.box:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

.red {
    background-color: orangered;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="box box1">
    <h3>Box 1</h3>
</div>
<div id="box2" class="box box2">
    <h3>Box 2</h3>
</div>
<div id="box3" class="box box3">
    <h3>Box 3</h3>
</div>
<div id="box4" class="box box4">
    <h3>Box 4</h3>
</div>
```

You can also use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax that will allow you to achieve the same with less code:

```js
let cbox = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
cbox.forEach(box => {
  box.addEventListener('click', () => box.classList.toggle("red"));
});
```

```css
*,
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.box {
    width: 10rem;
    height: 10rem;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    transition: .5s all;
}

h3 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.box:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

.red {
    background-color: orangered;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="box box1">
    <h3>Box 1</h3>
</div>
<div id="box2" class="box box2">
    <h3>Box 2</h3>
</div>
<div id="box3" class="box box3">
    <h3>Box 3</h3>
</div>
<div id="box4" class="box box4">
    <h3>Box 4</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: `.querySelectorAll()` doesn't return a `HTMLCollection` but a `NodeList`

Comment: So if its some kind of list it means that we can use a foreach loop also on the element cbox.

Comment: @EvangelosK., yes, you are right. You have to attach event listener to each element by using a loop.....thanks.

Comment: Thanks. But as far as performance concerns would that event fired 20 times if we have 20 items in the array? One for each element.?

Comment: @EvangelosK., there is no other way to attach event to all the elements in a list. As far as I know there will not be any performance issues for 20  elements which you can be worry about.....thanks.

Comment: How nice of you copying my answer and adding it to yours. Might be worth a read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362656/including-other-peoples-answer-into-your-own-accepted-answer

Answer (score 47):

**ES6 makes this a bit simpler:**

```
document.querySelectorAll(".box").forEach(box => 
  box.addEventListener("click", () => box.classList.toggle("red"))
)
```

Example implementation:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".box").forEach(box =>
  box.addEventListener("click", () => box.classList.toggle("red"))
)
```

```css
.box {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box.red {
  background-color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution with ES6 notation

Answer (score 14):

You can use `forEach` on the class or use **Event delegation**.

```
const cboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
function doit() {
    ... do something ...
}
cboxes.forEach(
  function(cbox) {
   cbox.addEventListener("click", doit,false);
  }
);
```

Notice that I changed your variable name.

**EventDelgation**

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="box1" class="box box1">
    <h3>Box 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="box2" class="box box2">
      <h3>Box 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="box3" class="box box3">
      <h3>Box 3</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="box4" class="box box4">
      <h3>Box 4</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JS part:

```
const parent = document.querySelector("#parent");

parent.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.target.classList.add('red');
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

Event delegation is much better and it uses fewer resources, as you only use 1 Event listener and no for loop.

Comment: `cboxes.forEach()` won't work with IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach !== NodeList.prototype.forEach`

Comment: easy polyfill fix to make forEach work in <= IE11 is:
`NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;`

Comment: or you can use the array spread operator like this: `[...document.querySelectorAll(".box")]`

Comment: `parent.addEventListener('click', (e) => { const tgt = e.target; if (tgt.classList.contains('box')) tgt.classList.add('red');
  console.log(tgt.id);
});`

Answer (score 9):

Rather than iterate through multiple elements and attach a lot of separate listeners, I would recommend using [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) and creating a **single delegated listener** at the root level, and then looking for matching elements that raised the event.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("box")) {
    doit();
  }
})
```

#### Further Reading

- [`window.EventTarget.prototype.addDelegatedListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55384108/1366033)
- [Adding click event listener to elements with the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21700364/1366033)
- [addEventListener on NodeList](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12362256/1366033)