# How to get clicked element's text using querySelectorAll and addEventListener in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a basic question in JS.
want to get the inner text of an element that the user clicked on.

I use

```
document.querySelectorAll(".key")
```

to get all the elements with the class key, and put event listener on them.

I want to know after the user click on one of them the inner html, and I get

```
TypeError: elements.addEventListener is not a function
```

I know this is basic but I am not understand what is wrong.
this is my script

```
<script>
    
   var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".key");
   elements.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      console.log(e.target.innerText);
   })
  
    </script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [addEventListener on a querySelectorAll() with classList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643302/addeventlistener-on-a-queryselectorall-with-classlist)

Comment: 1. querySelectorAll returns a collection 2. DELEGATE: find the closest static container - let's call it `id="myKeyContainer"`  and do `document.getElementById("myKeyContainer").addEventListener("click", function(e) { const tgt = e.target; if (tgt.classList.contains("key")) console.log(tgt.textContent); })`

Comment: TNX Achtung it solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

document.querySelectorAll() returns multiple items. Maybe you want to add a listener to each item.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".key");
   elements.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      console.log(e.target.innerText);
    });
   });
```

```html
<button class="key">Hello</button>
<button class="key">Hello2</button>
<button class="key">Hello3</button>
```