# Change Css of link that matches #anchor

Tags: javascript, joomla

I want the link in the right sidebar to change color if it matches the #anchor in the current page's url.

Example> If this is the URL: https://help.thinkiq.com/documentation/visualization-and-analysis-tools/custom-content/extensions-xy-scatter-with-timeshift#solution

Then the link "Solution" in the "ON THIS PAGE" sidebar module should change to green.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href="'+document.URL+'"]').forE‌​ach(function(elem){e‌​lem.className += ' current-link')});
```

And this in my custom.css

```
.current-link {
color: green;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran this solution successfully on your live site by writing the following CSS and JS changes:

**CSS**:

```
.current-link {
    color: green !important;
}
```

**JS**

```
document.querySelector('.sp-module ul>li>a[data-heading="' + window.location.hash.substr(1) + '"]').classList.add('current-link');
```

Effectively, you just need to:

1. access the hash value from the url
2. build the hash value into your js selector
3. add the desired class to the found element

You need to ensure that your custom styling overrides other pre-existing stylings.  `!important` did the job for me, but maybe it is possible to better specify the target element in your css.

---

To add an event listener on each of the links in your list so that the green styling changes on every anchor click, [choose from a range of js and jquery techniques/styles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50643302/2943403).  I am using a plain js approach with a slight delay to ensure that the action is triggered after the url is updated. While testing on your live site, without a delay the event seemed to fire before the url was updated.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.sp-module ul>li>a[data-heading]').forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.querySelectorAll('.sp-module ul>li>a[data-heading]').forEach(function(e) {
                e.classList.toggle("current-link", e.dataset.heading == window.location.hash.substr(1));
            });
        }, 100); // 1/10 of a second
    });
});
```

The above adds a listener to each anchor element on page load.  When any of the anchors are clicked, then all of the anchors will be iterated and the styling will be conditionally applied where appropriate.

An alternative technique (which may actually be faster -- though I don't think it matters in this case) is to unconditionally remove the `current-link` class on ALL anchor elements, then only re-add the class to the newly appropriate anchor.

Comment: I have added your JS into the head and made sure there is an !important.  But it is not working.

Comment: Well, it worked for me in the browser, so I can only assume that this is a timing issue.  Make sure that the javascript is executed after the page is fully loaded.

Comment: I got it to partially work.  But after it turns the first click green, it requires a page reload to change the next clicked link to green.

Comment: I am not at my computer now.  I think you are asking for the behavior to be triggered on page load AND you need an eventListener or mutationObserver to the same action when the hash value is changed or one of your anchor links is clicked. This is a new requirement to your initial question. See what you can achieve on your own for now.  Let me know how you go.

Comment: I'm confused if .classList.add('current-link') is the function of addEventListener.  Sorry I'm still learning...

Comment: `document.querySelector()` is the selector -- it targets something(s) when it is called.  `.classList.add('current-link')` is what is done to the target(s).  By simply writing this full line of code outside of an "eventListener", the action will be taken only once on page load.  What you want is for javascript to listen for onclick events on your list of links.  Whenever one of those links is clicked, you trigger the desired action.

Comment: @mod I've updated my answer with a snippet that proved to work properly on your live site from my browser tools.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `e‌​lem.classList.add('current-link')`

```js
console.log(document.URL)
document.querySelectorAll(`a[href="${document.URL}"]`)
  .forEach(elem => elem.classList.add('current-link'));
```

```css
.current-link {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
<a href="https://stacksnippets.net/js">Link 4</a>
<a href="#">Link 5</a>
<a href="#">Link 6</a>
<a href="#">Link 7</a>
```