# Browser console Error: Uncaught TypeError: allSections.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, console

I keep getting this error in my browser console when I inspect it: Uncaught TypeError: allSections.addEventListener is not a function
at PageTransitions (app.js:16:17)
at app.js:33:1

This is strange because in my vs code editer it isn't showing any errors. Here is the code I'm using below.

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
const secBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.controls');
const secBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.control');
const allSections = document.querySelectorAll('.main-content');

function PageTransitions(){
    
    for(let i = 0; i < secBtn.length; i++){
        secBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
            let currentBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.active-btn');
            currentBtn[0].className = currentBtn[0].className.replace('active-btn', '')
            this.className += ' active-btn';
        })
    }

    allSections.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
        const id = e.target.dataset.id;
        if(id) {
            secBtns.forEach((btn) => {
                btn.classList.remove('active')
            })
            e.target.classList.add('active')
            sections.forEach((section)=>{
                section.classList.remove('active')
            })

            const element = document.getElementById(id);
            element.classList.add('active');
        }
    })
}

PageTransitions();
```

also here is the html its for below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital@1&family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="main-content">
    <header class="section sec1 header active" id="home">
        
    </header>
    
    <main>
        <section class="section sec2 about" id="about"></section>
        <section class="section sec3 portfolio" id="portfolio"></section>
        <section class="section sec4 blogs" id="blogs"></section>
        <section class="section sec5 contacts" id="contact"></section>
    </main>

    <div class="controls">
        <div class="control control-1 active-btn" data-id="home">
            <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="control control-2 " data-id="about">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="control control-3 " data-id="portfolio">
            <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="control control-4 " data-id="blogs">
            <i class="far fa-newspaper"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="control control-5 " data-id="contact">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope-open"></i>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [addEventListener on a querySelectorAll() with classList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643302/addeventlistener-on-a-queryselectorall-with-classlist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
const secBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.controls');
const secBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.control');
const allSections = document.querySelectorAll('.main-content');
```

I was having the same problem. The problem here is that when you are using `querySelectorAll` on the `allSections` variable the error arises. `addEventListener` can be applied to a single element only and `querySelectorAll` is giving a list. To solve this use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I figured out before your post but that was definly the issue

Answer (score 1):

That's because `allSections` contains a NodeList since [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)  method returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors. ,  not just one element to listen on:

```
const allSections = document.querySelectorAll('.main-content');
```

So to solve that you need to loop over all sections with [`forEach`](https://%5B%60forEach%60%5D(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) and for section listen the click:

```
allSections.forEach((section) =>
    section.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const id = e.target.dataset.id;
    if (id) {
        secBtns.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.classList.remove("active");
        });
        e.target.classList.add("active");
        sections.forEach((section) => {
        section.classList.remove("active");
        });

        const element = document.getElementById(id);
        element.classList.add("active");
    }
    })
);
```

Comment: I just Fixed added a ref MDN, to read more about it!

Comment: I put the code in like you have but i keep getting  error message "expected ts(1005) for the last line

Answer (score -1):

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
const sectBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.controlls');
const sectBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.control');
const allSections = document.querySelectorAll('.main-content');


function PageTransitions() {
    //Button click active class
    for (let i = 0; i < sectBtn.length; i++) {
        sectBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            let currentBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.active-btn');
            currentBtn[0].className = currentBtn[0].className.replace('active-btn', '');
            this.className += 'active-btn';
        })
    }

    //Sections Active class
    allSections.forEach((section) =>
        section.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            const id = e.target.dataset.id;
            if (id) {
                //remove selected from the other btns
                sectBtns.forEach((btn) => {
                    btn.classList.remove('active')
                })
                e.target.classList.add('active')

                //hide other sections
                sections.forEach((section) => {
                    section.classList.remove('active')
                })

                const element = document.getElementById(id);
                element.classList.add('active')
            }
        }))
}

PageTransitions();
```

Comment: Where is your explanation?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).