# EventListener for querySelectorAll when more elements are added dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Looking at [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643302/addeventlistener-on-a-queryselectorall-with-classlist) Its possible to get event listeners for all in a class, but My issue is that in my program, user events generate more elements with that class, So if I run that function at the start of the program, i don't think it will work on all future elements added, so how would i code it so updates to include new elements of that class, while not having the performance issue of duplicating event listeners

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attach event to dynamic elements in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript)

Comment: Not really, as I wanted a different action for every element, which i didnt really see

Comment: But I've decided to add event listeners in a loop and remove element references in a loop, so I can add and remove event listeners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add event listeners to all nodes having the class initially, and then only add it to the newly created nodes. There are different ways of how you can implement this.

You could add an extra class to prevent adding multiple event listeners:

```js
function addEventListeners (selector) {
  let nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].classList.contains('has-event-listener')) {
      // skip nodes that already have the event listener
      continue;
    }
    nodes[i].addEventListener(/* ... */);
    nodes[i].classList.add('has-event-listener');
  }
}
```